# Why is this link not generated correctly in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink

I'm using codeigniter and the link to my categories don't work right. Maybe I don't understand some settings of the framework. I have in my configuration file set this base url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://hms.loc';
```

But when I click the "Home" category or any other category the link looks like:

```
http://localhost/hms/
```

But it should be:

```
http://hms.loc
```

When I click the "Rooms" category it is:

```
http://localhost/hms/rooms
```

How do I set this up correctly? And where can I specify such settings?

Comment: check how are you creating links. You should use `url helper`

Comment: Can you show us your code for those hrefs?

Comment: I used `<li><a href="<?php echo site_url()?>">Home</a> <i>/</i></li>` for home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `base_url()` or `site_url()` method from URL_Helper.

Please check the documentation:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

I use xampp, my web app folder name is "s_v", so i using

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/s_v/';
```

Answer (score 1):

If your project folder name is hms , define base_url as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/hms/';
```

Other wise check in html contain

```
<base href="http://localhost/hms/">
```